# How to debug array of char with more than 210 elements

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio, watch, locals

I'm working with Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop, and I would like to see the value of a variable.

This looks very easy: either open the "Locals" window and check the value, or add it to the "Watch" window, and the value can be read.

This is true indeed, but my variable is a char array (`typedef char T_BufCommandLine [32768];`), containing more than 210 characters, and I only see the first 210. After that, there are three dots ("..."), just mentioning that the array is not finished yet.

I know that I could expand the value of this variable, but the result is not very readable, and copying a part of this is completely impossible.

So my question: does anybody know how I can visualise the value of an array of char, which contains more than 210 characters, as one string without the "..."?

Comment: The standard way would be to `puts()` it. ;-) Sorry, could not resist. No, don't know a MSVC way, never mind me, I'm a troll and crawling back under my stone now.

Comment: try saving it to a file and use matlab to visualize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While on a breakpoint in the debugger, hover over your variable and click the down-arrow next to a "looking glass" icon; select "Text Visualizer".

[image]

Alternatively, use the Memory window:

[image]

Comment: I guess with this option the first `0x00` stops the visualizer.

Comment: @LPs - Most certainly. If you want raw bytes, use Memory window.

Answer (score 0):

One easy trick is to copy the element you want to a separate variable (or assign a pointer to the element) and add a breakpoint right after it is assigned to snoop it's value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using the Watch window, you can just explicitly specify the starting address. After all, it is just a plain old array. The debugger knows how to do pointer arithmetic. To watch the values beyond the first 210 elements, just do something like: `T_BufCommandLine+210,500`.

You could also use the Immediate Window, but you'll need to tell it exactly how long the array is. Something like: `?T_BufCommandLine[0],32768` will give you a massive dump.